# amb-bind on amp-list any value is not a valid result for [src]

Tags: amp-html

I use the pre-release version (001493855940942) of AMP.
The combination of amp-bind and and amp-list is not working.
Every value that I assign to [src] of amp-list end up with this error message wenn amp-state of currentFoo changed:

```
amp-bind: Expression evaluation error in "'https://localhost:3000' + fooList[currentFoo].bar_endpoint". "https://localhost:3000/api/bar/foo1" is not a valid result for [src].​​​
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be solved by [this pull request](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/commit/24f27278d5e4e5bf3a0382cd487490eb0c3e49a7)

Comment: This PR as nothing related to the original question.